# Adjust pixel format for an external display in OS X on iMac (early 2013)

Tags: macos, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I just replaced a custom build desktop with a new iMac (early 2013 model). One of my external monitors that I use needs a different pixel format than the one currently set as default in OS X.

On the previous desktop, I could easily adjust this using AMD's Catalyst Control Center like this:

[image]

For reference, my iMac has a NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

system preferences > displays.

This should allow you to customize them separately. If you mirror your displays you can optimize for a specific monitor. If you use each as it's own then customizing for both is possible

Comment: It turns out that I won't see this preference because I am using a Thunderbolt-to-HDMI adapter, and this is an HDMI setting. However, your answer is correct if this weren't the case so I've marked it as such. Thanks for the help!